# MVC 5 Validation Message doesn't work with using Ajax.beginForm

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC 5 and I have some problems that I couldn't find any answer I tried in different ways but no success.

I'm trying to make a validation for a list of users and passwords to make sure they enter data and they don't leave it blank, and after that to check if the user exists in the DB, but for some reason it doesn't work at all.

Controller : UserController.cs

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public ActionResult EditUser()
    {

        return PartialView("_EditUser", employeeRepository.GetAllEmployees());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public ActionResult UpdateEmployees(UserDetailViewModel[] EmployeeList)
    {



        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (EmployeeList != null)
            {
                employeeRepository.UpdateEmployee(EmployeeList);

                return PartialView("_EditUser", EmployeeList);



            }

        }
        ModelState.AddModelError("UserName", "User allready exists");
        return PartialView("_EditUser", "UserDetailViewModel");
    }
```

Model: UserViewModel.cs which it has 2 classes but i use the UserDetailViewModel

```
public class UserDetailViewModel
{

    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required (AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Username is required")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string WindowsID { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Required (AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public bool isAdmin { get; set; }
    public bool isExternal { get; set; }
    public bool isDeleted { get; set; }

    public bool isModified { get; set; }
}
```

View: _EditUser.cshtml

And i'm using as pop-up fancy_box.js the scripts.Render contains the jquery.validate.js",jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js",jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js",

```
    @model OfficeManager.Interfaces.ViewModels.UserDetailViewModel[]

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateEmployees", "User", new AjaxOptions
{
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        OnSuccess = "usersSavedSuccessfully",
        OnFailure = "failedSaveUsers"
    }, new { id = "editUser" }))
{
    <div class="edit-pop-up gray2">
        <div class="edit-title orangeGray"><h3>Edit User</h3></div>
        <table id="Edit_user_table" align="center">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td><p>UserName:</p></td>
                    <td><p>WindowsID:</p></td>
                    <td><p>Password:</p></td>
                    <td><p>Admin:</p></td>
                    <td><p>External:</p></td>
                    <td><p>Deleted:</p></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="6">
                        <div id="edit_user_inner">
                            <table id="inner_edit_user_table">
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr id="item-@(item.ID)">
                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => item.UserName, new { @class = "editUser" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessage("UserName")</td>

                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => item.WindowsID, new { @class = "" })</td>

                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => item.Password, new { @class = "" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.UserName)</td>

                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => item.isAdmin)</td>
                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => item.isExternal)</td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.EditorFor(model => item.isDeleted)
                                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.isModified)
                                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div style="margin-left: 5px; padding-right:14px; padding-bottom: 16px; border: 0px none; float: right;;">
            <input id="add_user" onclick="AddRow()" type="button"  value="Add New User" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-left: auto; margin-top: 20px; font-size: 20px; width:auto;" />
            <input id="save_user" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-left: auto; margin-top: 20px; font-size: 20px; width: auto;" />
            <input id="cancel_user" type="button" onclick="$.fancybox.close();" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-default " style="margin-left: auto; margin-top: 20px; font-size: 20px; width: auto;" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

And when I'm pressing the submit button i get this error:

```
POST http://localhost:54238/User/UpdateEmployees?Length=4 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

But the message doesn't appear but it goes `onFailure` on `Ajax.BeginForm`.

So what could be the cause? I tried in different ways, the only way I managed to make it work is by using a jQuery and instead of return `View` I used a return JSON with custom message and I changed it with jQuery by reading the response from controller, but that's not the way it's supposed to be done.

Comment: I found the problem with ?Length=4 it was because i didn't give null to route values.

Later edit: i did some several changes in the code. 

1) After checking on different ways of Ajax.BeginForm i added a new div with id=Test (example) outside the Ajax.BeginForm and in the Ajax.BeginForm options i added UpdateTargetId="test"

2) in the Controller at HTTP POST UpdateEmployees i changed from this -> return PartialView("_EditUser", "UserDetailViewModel"); into this -> return PartialView("_EditUser", employeeRepository.GetAllEmployees());. 

The problem now is it shows mandatory to all usernames

Comment: Doesn't matter found out that too, it was because i added ModelState.AddModelError("UserName","Text to show");

Answer (score 0):

in simple project 
controller :

```
 public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        public AccountController()
        {
            HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = true;
        }
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Account model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return PartialView("Thanks");
        }
        return PartialView("Index");
    }
}
```

viewModel :

```
public class Account
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 4)]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 4)]
    [Compare("ConfirmPassword")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 4)]
    [Compare("Password")]
    [DisplayName("Confirm Password")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [AgeValidation(21)]
    [DisplayName("Birth Date")]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

view:

```
<body>
    <div id="ParentDiv">
        <div id="Aj">
@{ var ajaxOptions = new AjaxOptions
       {
           UpdateTargetId = "ParentDiv",
           HttpMethod = "POST"
       }; }
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Account", ajaxOptions))
{
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <input type="submit" />
}
</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and you can see > http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/460893/Unobtrusive-AJAX-Form-Validation-in-ASP-NET-MVC